# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start causes error "No application is associated with the specified file for this operation" when deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, webforms, system.diagnostics

I am new to c# and have created a web form using ASP.NET 4.7.2 and Visual Studio 2019. One of my buttons links to a url using:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("www.google.com", "_blank");
```

However, when I debug my app locally, it works fine. Once I deploy the app and click on the same button, this error shows up:

```
Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No application is associated with the specified file for this operation
```

This points directly at the line where I make the call to `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032151/no-application-is-associated-with-the-specified-file-for-this-operation-vb-net

Comment: Not sure I get this right. It seems to me that the question you linked suggested that I should have an empty string passed to Process.Start... but how would this open the url?

Comment: This means that there is no standard process to open links on the machine

Comment: sorry i have edit my comment!

Comment: But the machine can open that url... it does not work when it's deployed

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30979896/1390548

Comment: Not sure  @Jawad. I have no problem running this locally. The problem is when the app is deployed to the cloud.

Comment: did you try to put the full url including scheme: `https://www.google.de`

Comment: Yes I did but it still doesn't work